# Using both access and refresh tokens for refreshing them

Tags: jwt, access-token, refresh-token

Was investigating how to work with JWT and found not obvious thing for me:
Why for refreshing access token are not using both access and refresh tokens but only refresh token?

In this case we will be able to:

1. Verify access token signature, even if it is expired.
2. Get from access token information from payload, which may help in finding refresh token in database.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear and is assuming some things that may not be true. Neither access tokens not refresh tokens have to be JWTs and JWTs are not specific to OAuth2 (which defines access and refresh tokens, but doesn't say how they should be implemented).

The audience for access tokens and refresh tokens is also different - access tokens are sent to a (possibly separate) resource server (the issuing authorization server may not even have kept a copy if they are self contained). Refresh tokens are sent to the authorization server.

Locating either type of token in a database (assuming they aren't self-contained tokens like JWTs) should never be a problem because they should be unique tokens which make ideal primary keys for a database table. So there would be no reason to send an expired access token as part of a refresh request.

Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way :).

Comment: In addition to this nice answer, the access token to refresh is supposed to be invalid (expired) thus sending it is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for answers!
I think, I was needed to give a little bit more information. In my case I don't have authorization server, only one server. And one user may have different refresh and access tokens, because one user may connect to server from different places(in my case different mobile devices). When application find out that need to refresh access token, it may send refresh and access token or send refresh token only, but in this case server need information about device. Access token has such information in payload, so I thought that sending both of them will be better.